# Yarn 2+ equivalent to --modules-folder option from Classic Yarn?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

Is there any Yarn 2+ equivalent to `yarn install --modules-folder C:/some_folder` command from Classic Yarn?

I've searched like crazy and haven't found any simple way to replicate the seemingly basic option they removed for some reason.

The only viable options I've found so far are to do a regular yarn install, then create a symlink from the "`--modules-folder`" to the actual node_modules folder. Or to just move the entire folder after the install finishes.

I'd like to avoid both of these as they are clunky, and either potentially buggy or significantly worse in performance than just doing an install in the desired location to begin with.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: There is an open issue on this problem @ https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/5441. It hasn't gotten much attention.